# Варианты обновления всей таблицы после любого insert or update Postgresql

Tags: postgresql, plpgsql

есть таблица и в ней через функцию осуществляется пересчет показателей которые аффектят все строки в таблице, простым триггером вида:

```sql
CREATE TRIGGER сheck_trigger 
after INSERT OR update OR DELETE 
ON public.[TABLE] 
FOR EACH ROW 
EXECUTE PROCEDURE has_child();
```

зависает таблица с ошибкой:

```
Error synchronizing data with database

Reason:
SQL Error [54001]: ERROR: stack depth limit exceeded
  Hint: Increase the configuration parameter "max_stack_depth" (currently 2048kB), after ensuring the platform's stack depth limit is adequate.
```

Вопрос: Какие есть методы решения данной ситуации , добавлю желательно реализовать через автоматизацию стредствами Postgres - решение через крон понятны, но не желательны

ps. Сейчас реалтизовал простым запросом, но это не решает вопросы автоматизации.

```sql
UPDATE [TABLE] 
SET sub_level = has_child(level_id) 
where level_id IN (SELECT level_id 
                   from [TABLE]
                   where active is true);
```

Comment: Жуть какая... а зачем на каждую изменяемую строку пересчитывать всю таблицу? когда уже следующая строка опять приведёт к пересчёту? используйте statement-based триггер, что ли...

Comment: Но ещё разумнее - опубликовать собственно задачу, которую Вы пытаетесь столь неудачно решить, а не попытку решения.

Comment: Почему жуть? я сообщил что все записи в таблице аффектят друг друга, соответственно и задача сводится к обновлению всей таблицы - благо записей в ней порядка 100 больше не будет - это каталог категорий с под категориями

Comment: Дерево, что ли? а зачем вообще что-то там хранить, если 100 записей с тупым parent-child обрабатываются мухой, со всеми "древесными" наворотами типа уровня и полного пути, простейшим рекурсивным CTE?

Comment: хммм, хороший вопрос, об этом я не подумал. Спасибо!